# Using NodeJS with monobd ($all function)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am implementing a search by keywords with mongodb and node JS, but I see that there is the operator $all in Mongo that selects the documents where the field holds an array and contains all elements.

Here is my source code with node JS

```
exports.find = function(req, res) {
    var b=req.params.search;
    var query = {};
    var cadsrch = b.split(' ');
    var l = cadsrch.length;
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if(cadsrch[i]!=''){
          query[i]=new RegExp('^'+cadsrch[i], 'i');
        }
    }

    db.collection('publicacion', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({tags: {'$all':query}},{title:true,content:true}).limit(5).toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.jsonp(items);
        });
    });
};
```

The above source does not work, but this query works in Mongo->

```
db.publication.find({tags:{$all:['chevrolet','car']}})
```

and the strange thing is with '$in' instead '$all' works, but it would be useful to work with '$all' to implement exact searches

Answer (score 0):

The query below is working because you're not using `Regexp` in the `$all` array:

```
db.publication.find({tags:{$all:['chevrolet','car']}})
```

I believe adding `RegExp` into `$all` is forcing the query to find an array element that contains all of your expressions together.

For example, execute below:

```
db.publicacion.find({"tags": {$all: [/chevrolet/i, /car/i]}})
```

This will not return any result because it will search for a tag that contains both `chevrolet` and `car` keywords into a single string like: `["chevrolet-cars", "chevrolet-car", "carchevrolet", "chevroletcar"]`.

If you want to use multiple `RegExp` to find the documents that have similar tags, use Mongoose Aggregate functions: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html